# How to pack jar dependecies in JavaEE web-fragment project?

Tags: java, primefaces, gradle, wildfly, web-fragment

I have a web-fragment project. The output of this project is a JAR FILE called **fragment.jar**.

This fragment.jar is then copied into my MAIN PROJECT's WEB-INF/lib. Of course, output of the main project called is a war file called web.war.

The fragment.jar has web-fragmnet.xml in it. The whole war file is deployed to WildFly 9. Wildfly recognizes the fragment.jar as a web-fragment. However, Inside the web-fragment, there are some JSF files with dependencies for Primefaces. **What I don't know is where to put the Primefaces dependencies (jars) to avoid ClassNotFound exceptions.**

I tried to create Gradle multiproject builds, having the fragment itself as a subproject. This works, Gradle copies all the subproject dependencies into WEB-INF/lib. This however, requires the whole project to be present on the machine. **But I want to be able to distribute just the fragment.jar with all it's dependencies.**

EDIT: I've tried to create a fat jar using Gradle's ShadowPlugin. Things moved on a little, but this time I get another exceptions: [EXCEPTIONS](http://pastebin.com/fVEskTQm)

Comment: Build `fragment.jar` as a fat jar - using gradle shadow plugin.

Comment: I've tried it and edited my question. New problems occured :(

Comment: Please post code and stacktraces inline